# jQuery Text box not showing

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to show a text box when some one click on the click me button [Check here](http://prntscr.com/6tpi12)

When the user click on the "click me" button I want to display the area colored box.

Here is my code.

HTML

```
<h1>Welcome to QuickSchools</h1>


<div id="section" style="display:none;">Here is a new section</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting</div>
<button type="button" id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

CSS

```
#section{
background-color:red;
margin-left: 363px;
width: 200px;
height: 150px;
margin-top: -61px}
```

jQuery

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
$("#section").show();});
```

Can any one help ?

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nz7z9dtu/

Comment: Multiple IDs aren't allowed on page. Id must be unique.

Comment: have you added $(document).ready(function(){})

Comment: which section you want to display ? all section with `#section` ?

Comment: Your jsfiddle works. I don't understand what is your question?

Comment: @ReneKorss I want to show the textbox as it has been shown in the screenshot as it is here: http://prntscr.com/6tpi12

Comment: See my answer. Edited it to break `h1` correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see jsfiddle -http://jsfiddle.net/nz7z9dtu/9/

In order to achieve what you are looking for - [prntscr.com/6tpi12](http://prntscr.com/6tpi12) - you should decrease the width of the 'content' class div on click as well as displaying the 'section' class. To do this your jquery should be as follows:

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
    $(".section").show();
    $(".content").css("width", "70%")
});
```

Comment: I want the paragraph and text box should come as it have shown in the screenshot as shared.

Comment: ok, that is based on the css and html.  I suspect the reason your jquery isn't working is due to not having the click function within the document.ready function, provided your jsfiddle works as you like

Comment: Can you help me with the css. ? I am struggling with the css i suppose. Functionality wise it is working with the jQuery. check the jsfiddle in the updated question.

Comment: ah ok, you want it to appear in the div?

Comment: An explanation of the problem and solution would be helpful.

Comment: @showdev The problem the user was facing was that he wanted his div to appear in his html as it is in this page prntscr.com/6tpi12 - The solution that I provided was to decrease the width of the  'content' div and to display the 'section' div on click. I have also added this advice to the answer. Is this suffice? If not, please let me know so that I can ensure to follow SO practice